# When should the ‘rdbms’ tag be applied?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I would assume that the `rdbms` tag is easily assumed for just about every question on `dba.stackexchange.com`.

For those questions specifically about non-relational DBMSen, the `non-relational` tag can be used.

Is the `rdbms` tag redundant? Should it be removed in edits and deprecated?

Comment: **database** is a good candidate for redundant list. See these [questions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) are migrated from SO were 'database' tag is necessary but not here...

Comment: Getting rid `database` gets my vote too :)

Comment: @JackDouglas, @drachenstern - `database` tag has been removed from nine questions. Hope we are all agree with keeping `rdbms` tag.

Comment: @Sandy - not me but I'm happy to be told I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its redundant.

Its the fact, almost every question in this site will be related to [rdbms](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdbms) one way or other. We can make use of this tag to those specific questions were there is no specific database is applicable a.k.a [database-agnostic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-agnostic)

This tag will be suitable with tags like [database-design](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-design) and [database-recommendation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-recommendation)

Hope this makes sense :)

@drachenstern - Creating synonym is not an option for this particular case. Its used for map look-alike tags [oracle-10g](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-10g) to [oracle10g](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle10g) see dba tag [synonyms](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) so far.

[What are tag synonyms? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)
[Tag Folksonomy and Tag Synonyms](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/)

Comment: Getting rid of `rdbms` gets my vote

Comment: @Sandy ~ I still don't see, but this is why we have many moderators. I defer to you on this one, without question.

Comment: @sandy - sorry I misread your answer, I thought you meant that there is no need for [tag:rdbms] because it applies to virtually every question. I'd suggest a "non-relational" tag (if we dont have one already) for the rare exception - wouldn't that be more useful?

Comment: @JackPDouglas - `rdbms`, `nosql`, `object-model` and other types of similar tags will be useful for questions like "I'm in a <situation>, is it best to use 'database1' or 'database2'; or do I need to consider 'database3'?"

Comment: @JackPDouglas - yes, we can use `non-relational` if necessary...

Comment: @Sandy - ok. Is your intention that every question will be tagged with a vendor tag (eg Oracle) or the rdbms tag, or object-relational and so on?

Comment: @JackPDouglas - Yes. So far all questions follow this method, to ensure the audience/peers identify questions concerned with particular database at first glance in the list page. And it will be easy for experts to jump in answer, who subscribed those vendor tags.

Answer (score -1):

#### Personally I think the [rdbms](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdbms) should go away.

The only answer in favor of the tag currently states:

> almost every question in this site will be related to [rdbms](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdbms) one way or other.

According to this logic the tag adds little to no value. Also I hope people answering a [sql-server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) question don't need to be reminded that SQL Server is relational....

The biggest valid use case I see for this is in conjunction with [database-recommendation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-recommendation) questions. The normal method to add subcategories to a tag is adding a suffix. The tag [database-recommendation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-recommendation) is already so long I don't think [database-recommendation-relational](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-recommendation-relational) works. Instead I propose tags like:

- [recommendation-rdbms](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-rdbms)
- [recommendation-nosql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-nosql) or [recommendation-non-rdbms](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-non-rdbms)

As a bonus, this would avoid and/or provide an antidote to recommendation questions that add the parent tag for every RDBMS they can think of.