# Relational vs. RDBMS vs. Relational-Theory

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms

The [relational](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relational) tag has a description that seems very similar to the [rdbms](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdbms) tag, but it seems to be used often in lieu of the [relational-theory](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relational-theory) tag.*

Relational short description:

> Category of database management systems characterized by the ability to join two data sets by matching on common fields, using mathematics-based relational logic.

RDBMS short description:

> Relational Database Management System, a widely used type of database management system characterized by its extensive use of joining as a core operational principle.

I think we should drop the [relational](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relational) tag.  That would serve to remove some of the ambiguity between the three tags.  Alternatively it would be nice to develop some clear guidance on when the tag [relational](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relational) is more appropriate that the other tags.

---

*: Click each tag for a list of questions.

Comment: I agree. the "relational" tag is very often misapplied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems [relational](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relational) ought to be a synonym of [relational-theory](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relational-theory) and then merged. I'll wait to see what the community response is to this idea before taking any action.

Update: the synonym has been created and a merge performed.

The [rdbms](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdbms) tag issue is addressed in a separate meta discussion.

Answer (score 3):

It has been over a month and no one has answered so I'm adding my own answer.

1. I think the tag [rdbms](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdbms) should be [removed and replaced](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2378/72091).
2. I think the tag [relational](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relational) should be just removed, because I don't understand where/how it really adds value.
3. I think the tag [relational-theory](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relational-theory) should stay.